# Tomcat manager not showing up with embedded version

Tags: java, maven, tomcat6, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm using the tomcat maven plugin, version 2.0-beta-1 with the tomcat6 version. I can use the command

```
mvn tomcat6:run
```

And i can access my webapp. But I can't access the manager app. I got a blank page when I try :

```
http://localhost:8080/manager
http://localhost:8080/manager/html
```

I tried to configure the tomcat-users.xml file, but still nothing...

Would it be the reason why the shutdown command doesn't work?

```
mvn tomcat6:shutdown
```

Any idea why it's not working? I've been googling a long time but didn't find anything.

Comment: I didn't add any extra <configuration> parameter in my pom.xml file

Answer (score 2):

The manager app is not deployed with the embeded version.
What is your use case ? CTRL+c will shutdown maven and the embeded tomcat.

Comment: My case, is I want to run it from Eclipse as an external tool. But if I stop the process launched inside the eclipse console, Tomcat is still running. The "children" thread of the console which is the tomcat JVM isn't kill. I wish there would be a way to shut it down from Eclipse, and not with Ctrl+C

Comment: the children thread in this case in the Maven build thread. Tomcat embeded is started in the same thread (no jvm forked). Sorry I don't use eclipse but maybe there is a way to stop the maven build ?

Comment: Only with CTRL+C... :( With jetty it works if you configure a "stop" port

Answer (score 2):

Of course @olamy is correct (he should know, he built it) in that the Tomcat Maven plugins don't run the manager app.

BUT, if you are looking to just run your WAR from within Eclipse and have a ton of control over the servlet container, I highly recommend running embedded Tomcat within a simple Java command line app. You can even debug into your WAR code, and when it quits, it takes down Tomcat too.

I wrote a little wrapper app which serves my needs here (it also hosts Jetty and Glassfish but not as completely):
https://bitbucket.org/mckamey/war-bootstrap

The code I use which specifically sets up and runs Tomcat basically looks like this:

```
Tomcat server = new Tomcat();
server.setBaseDir(new File("tomcat").getCanonicalPath());
server.setPort(port);

// I have a Map<String,String> of CONTEXT=WAR pairs
for (String contextPath : contexts.keySet()) {
    String warPath = contexts.get(contextPath);
    server.addWebapp(contextPath, warPath);
}

server.start();

// do something to prevent this thread from ending
System.out.println("Press ENTER to exit.");
System.in.read();

server.stop();
server.destroy();
```

And there are plenty more examples out there:
http://people.apache.org/~markt/presentations/2010-11-04-Embedding-Tomcat.pdf